# How to enable add-ons via scripting?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I am trying to install and enable the add-on using the API on CentOS 7.6.1810 64bit. The add-on can be installed into add-on folder and there is no error reported when I enable the add-on. However, the status of the add-on just keep false. I tried enable and disable the internal add-on, and it works fine. This is the script I used to print all add-ons and enable my external add-on:

[image]

**Q:** How to enable add-ons using via scripting?

Comment: What is the error message? It would be helpful if you paste your code instead of image.

Comment: Hi. If you need to include code please paste it in to the question instead of just adding an image of it. This will make it easier for people to test your code. At the minute they would have to type it out themselves. Thanks.